# How to make the translations for verification email template in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, emails, i18n-l10n

I used [User verification](http://drupal.org/project/user_verify) module for sending verification email to users and it worked perfectly. After that, I wanted to add the multilingual function for the website (use http://drupal.org/project/i18n) but I couldn't find any places to make or edit the translations for verification email template.

How can i make the translations for verification email template?